# Getting error when loading data from db to class object

Tags: c#, ienumerable

i have a class customer. in which i am trying to load data from the access db database.

Customer class structure is below:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustAddress { get; set; }
        public string PnoneNo { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public string CstNo { get; set; }
        public string DlNo { get; set; }
        public decimal BalAmt { get; set; }
            }
```

and my table structure in db is as below:

[image]

now when i am trying to load data in customer class it is throwing an error:

"Specified cast is not valid."

for loading data in to class i am using below code:

```
public static List<Customer> LoadListItems(string strTable, string strOrderBy)
        {
            List<Customer> lstCustomer=null;
            try
            {
                DataUtility objDataUtility = new DataUtility();
                DataTable objCustomerList = objDataUtility.LoadCustomerInfo(strTable, strOrderBy);

                lstCustomer= objCustomerList.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
                        new Customer
                        {
                            CustomerId = row.Field<int>("CID"), //throwing error for this line
                            CustomerName = row.Field<string>("salPNm"),
                            CustAddress = row.Field<string>("cadd"),
                            MobileNo = row.Field<string>("cmbl"),
                            PnoneNo = row.Field<string>("cph"),
                            DlNo = row.Field<string>("cDlN"),
                            CstNo = row.Field<string>("cTin"),
                            BalAmt = row.Field<decimal>("cobal")
                        }).ToList();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return lstCustomer;

        }
```

In above method `CustomerId = row.Field<int>("CID"),` is throwing an error coz when i commented this line it is working fine.
Please help me how can i get the int values from iennumrable list.

Thanks in Advance.
Eshwer

Comment: Your `try - catch` block is redundant if you just rethrow the exception in the `catch`.

Comment: Try `long` or `decimal`.

Comment: Rather than trying to guess what the type being used us, just get the actual type and adjust accordingly. Debug and inspect the column's `DataType`: `objCustomerList.Columns["CID"].DataType`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with -

```
CustomerId = Convert.ToInt64(row.Field<int>("CID"));
```

Also, check the value by applying `Quick Watch` over this line - `row.Field<int>("CID")`. See if it's `not null` and what's the value its returning.

Comment: I think this will not work. CustomerId is still an Int32 and the exception is thrown by the extension method .Field<T>().

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Customer
{
    public Int64 CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustAddress { get; set; }
    public string PnoneNo { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string CstNo { get; set; }
    public string DlNo { get; set; }
    public decimal BalAmt { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
CustomerId = row.Field<Int64>("CID")
```

I think that your identity is a long integer.

Comment: Hi thanks all to reply and help me to solve the problem specially jeff. the problem was data was coming in Int16 type.